# Netbook as a server with external hard drive

Tags: server, lubuntu, samba, external-hdd

I got a netbook (and old LG X100) running Lubuntu 16.04 with two external hard disks.

My main goal is to access one of the external drives on two separate windows machines (one in the same home, other in my office) and possibly even map this drive on Windows. IF possible. The other external drive I would like to sync with the other for backup.

I don´t have linux skills and for now the best I could arrange is to access this kind of "server" using team viewer and dropbox to drag and drop files to the external drive. I could sync it, using a third party app but not automatically...

So I am suffering a lot to try to understand and install and configure stuff like OwnCloud, Webmin, Samba, and so on which I found in some online tutorials... but I could never even realize if is that what I need!

Any hints? Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty good and simple guide on how to create a Samba share that can be read by Windows machines (note that this only handles the Ubuntu part, you would need to search for other Guides on how to mount it as drive in Windows). It also uses the command line, which means, in case the Netbook is to slow to handle a GUI, it would technically apply to Ubuntu Server too:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20Create%20a%20Network%20Share%20Via%20Samba%20Via%20CLI%20(Command-line%20interface/Linux%20Terminal)%20-%20Uncomplicated,%20Simple%20and%20Brief%20Way!

If you want to sync files between two drives, I recommend you to do some searching about a tool called "rsync" and how to automate it